# Angular2 create directive with controls

Tags: angular

I want to create some directive that can be controlled from some initBtn (just like on pureJS). SetUp init class for some btn, that setUp plugin class for some el and on init trigger playing will begin.

But directive in Angular2 can be assigned to one element (What if I want to place initBtn in different place from  plugin container) ? How I can do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please add some code that demontrates what you trx to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Gunter. Please: https://plnkr.co/edit/Emj9HxFRPURTpjFCSkNK?p=preview

in this case it's two virtual components and in one of them I placed init plugin btn and in other - plugin container.   How I can make it in directive? Because directive applied to one element and I can't move some init  outside this. elem.   I can  place directive withoud init btn  and  add to parent component some  init method. But it's not good because in others components I should write this init method. How I can move init btn to some place and save possibility to init this plugin. Thanks.